# How to get documents size(in bytes) in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I need to get the size of the documents of the query results.

Example:

```
this is a document. (19bytes).
this is also a document. (24bytes)
content:{"a":"this is a document", "b":"this is also a document"}(53bytes)
```

When I query for the document in ES, I will get the documents above as a result. So, the size of both documents is 32bytes. I need the 32bytes in Elasticsearch as a result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does your document only contain a single field? I'm not sure this is 100% of what you want, but generally you can calculate the length of fields and either store them with the document or calculate them at query time (but this is a slow operation and I would avoid it if possible).

So here's an example with a test document and the calculation for the field length:

```
PUT test/_doc/1
{
  "content": "this is a document."
}

POST test/_update_by_query
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must_not": [
        {
          "exists": {
            "field": "content_length"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "script": {
    "source": """ 
if(ctx._source.containsKey("content")) {
  ctx._source.content_length = ctx._source.content.length();
} else {
  ctx._source.content_length = 0;
}
"""
  }
}

GET test/_search
```

The query result is then:

```
{
  "took" : 6,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 5,
    "successful" : 5,
    "skipped" : 0,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : 1,
    "max_score" : 1.0,
    "hits" : [
      {
        "_index" : "test",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "1",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "content" : "this is a document.",
          "content_length" : 19
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

BTW there are 19 characters (including spaces and dots in that one). If you want to exclude those, you'll have to add some more logic to the script. I would be careful with bytes BTW, since UTF8 might use more than one byte per character (like `höhe`) and this script is really only counting characters.

Then you can easily use the length in queries and aggregations.

If you want to calculate the size of all the subdocuments combined, use the following:

```
PUT test/_doc/2
{
  "content": {
    "a": "this is a document",
    "b": "this is also a document"
  }
}

POST test/_update_by_query
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must_not": [
        {
          "exists": {
            "field": "content_length"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "script": {
    "source": """
if(ctx._source.containsKey("content")) {
  ctx._source.content_length = 0;
  for (item in ctx._source.content.entrySet()) {
    ctx._source.content_length += item.getValue().length();
  }
}
"""
  }
}

GET test/_search
```

Just note that `content` can either be of the type text or have a subdocument, but you can't mix that.

Comment: Thanks, @xeraa. How can I handle for a nested dictionary as value for a content field? .

Comment: You mean for fields like `content.foo` and `content.bar`? Either hardcode or you should be able to loop through them. Probably something like the following, but I haven't tested that: `for (sub in ctx._source.content) { ctx._source.content_length += sub.length(); }`

Comment: like that @xeraa. I will check with your solution. will let you know.

Comment: I am getting error @xeraa. could you please help me. I am adding that example in the question.

Comment: Added a complete example. I was missing some extra parameters ;)

Comment: Thank you very much @xeraa.I will check and let you know :):)

Comment: But suppose if I have int value in content. How can I handle that @xeraa. In my case int also there.

Comment: for the above example, I am getting the below error.
TypeError: string indices must be integers. @xeraa

Comment: You can either have a text field in content or you can have subdocuments. You can't mix them, because the mapping would throw an error otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

There's no way to get elasticsearch docs size by API. The reason is that the doc indexed to Elasticsearch takes different size in the index, depending on whether you store _all, which fields are indexed, and the mapping type of those fields, doc_value and more. also elasticsearch uses deduplication and other methods of compaction, so the index size has no linear correlation with the original documents it contains.

One way to work around it is to calculate the document size in advance before indexing it, and add it as another field in the doc, i.e. doc_size field. then you can query this calculated field, and run aggregations on it.

Note however that as I stated above this does not represent the size of the index, and might be completely wrong - for example if all the docs contain a very long text field with the same value, then Elasticsearch would only store that long value once and reference to it, so the index size would be much smaller.

Answer (score 1):

Elasticsearch now has a _size field, which can be enabled in mappings.
Once enabled, this gives out data size in Bytes.

```
GET <index_name>/_doc/<doc_id>?stored_fields=_size
```

[Elasticsearch official doc](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/plugins/current/mapper-size-usage.html)